# How can I unbold the list of figures and list of tables If I use \boldmath equations in the caption?

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, equations, captions, boldmath

I'm sorry, but I do not understand how \caption works completely.  I use \caption{} in order to enumerate and name automatically my figures and tables.  My problem is that sometimes I have to write some \equation{} inside this \caption and font type  in the caption between the simple text and the equation is different. In order to solve this problems I have decided to use \boldmath{} when I use this \equation{} inside the \caption{} in order to make it similar. However, at this time, when I create my \listoffigures I see this bold mathematical equation in some terms of the captions. How can I solve this problem?

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{./figuras/Multifase/IcrmsAVcppmax/OndasAnalisisIcAvcpp_5fases.pdf}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Inverter's input current and \dcl{} voltage ripple for a range
    of \boldmath{$0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/5$} in 2M+2L modulations.}
    \label{figure:Ondas IcAvcpp_5fases}
\end{figure} 

\listoffigures
```

[image]

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You can use the optional argument for the caption, `\caption[text in LoF without bold math]{text in document with bold math}`.

Comment: unrelated but `\boldmath` does not take an argument, use `\boldmath` not `\boldmath{...}`

Comment: I really do not understand *why* you are using bold math in the captions. You mention "_font type in the caption between the simple text and the equation is different_" which actually suggests something is weird with your font setup.

Comment: Using the optional argument for the caption suits me. Thank you very much.  I think I have explained my situation... I do not understand completely how does the configuration of the document works, I just work on the .tex one friend gave me so, I do not know how to change my  font setup in order to just change \equation{} font or LoF font type. Thank you for Your help. Using \caption[text in LoF without bold math] suits me.